# AIC and BIC for wrong models!

Tags: model-selection, aic, bic

If the models we consider for the data are wrong, what happens to the model selection with AIC or BIC as the data increases?
Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried simulating it and finding out for yourself? For example in R... or Python or SAS or SPSS or whatever else can be used to generate data and calculate AIC and BIC

Comment: "Wrong" in what sense? You need to give us more details.

Comment: @Tim, *wrong* usually means not coinciding with the data generating process, as in *all models are wrong*. Is there another meaning?

Comment: @RichardHardy in “all models are wrong”, all of them are wrong, so it would be a non-issue, wouldn’t it?

Comment: @Tim, I am not sure I understand. I am curious if you have another way of interpreting *wrong* in addition to *the model does not not coincide with the data generating process*.